# Access repository where direct access to the repository's URL is blocked

Tags: ssh, apt, firewall, proxy, repository

A Raspberry Pi is located behind a hardware firewall which is configured to block all outgoing communication to any IP except my server (all ports are allowed) and to block all incoming communication except the response requested by the Pi (obviously from my server). I can access the Pi from my server by tunneling within a SSH connection initiated by the Pi to my server. The firewall cannot be reconfigured.

```
RaspPi ---F/W---> MyServer <---Internet---> Repositories
```

How can I update the Pi as it cannot communicate directly to the repository URLs?

```
sudo apt-get -y update
```

Comment: Install an HTTP proxy (listening on localhost only, to avoid exposure) on the bastion host and configure the Pi to use this proxy server?

Comment: You could allow `MyServer` to be a repository mirror.

Comment: @Celada  I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353955/apt-get-install-via-tunnel-proxy-but-ssh-only-from-client-side.  Maybe?

Comment: @KevinO  How does a repository mirror work?

Comment: Essentially `MyServer` would obtain the various repo packages, and then provide them. We run a mirror so that our local network machines accesses packages directly rather than every machine running out and downloading the same file from the internet. It might be overkill (the proxy approach might work better for a single machine). [This link discusses a local mirror](https://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror), but I have no direct `apt-get` experience (we're a RHEL shop).

Comment: @KevinO  Thanks, I will check it out.  The server is RHEL. Will this cause issues?

Comment: I do not believe it should pose any issues, since the files are served via http, and the repository is just files that are offered up from a given directory hierarchy. There are some places (e.g., [mirrors.tummy.com](http://mirrors.tummy.com)) that serve multiple O/S, so that is another data point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 and a half solutions - Do a ssh tunnel or set up a mirror or rather proxy connections to the mirror for the pi

**Use a ssh tunnel.**

From the pi, start a screen session or something and connect to your remote server via ssh with some arguments

`ssh -L8000:hostname.of.apt.repo:80 user@remotebox`

Then point your `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries to something like http://localhost:8000/raspbian - mine looks like

`deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free`

so I'd change it to

`deb http://localhost:8000/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free`

And my ssh command would be

`ssh -L8000:archive.raspbian.org:80 user@remotebox`

Then run your normal `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` or whatever you want to do

**Turn your box into the repository**

Well, you probably don't want to mirror gigs of files for just one machine, so consider setting up a proxy (with authentication) and setting it to be used in your `apt.conf` file on the pi.

Comment: For option 1, is `/etc/apt/sources.list` (`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`) or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` the source list. (`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui`)?  EDIT.  By your answer, I take it it is the later.

Comment: For option 2, there isn't an `apt.conf` file.  Also, for the proxy, will squid be acceptable?

Comment: Edited to clarify the /etc/apt/sources.list - but be aware that apt will bring in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list as well.  If you'd rather go the proxy route, here's an answer on configuring a pi to use a proxy for apt - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322280/how-can-i-configure-a-http-proxy-for-apt-get    The `apt.conf` reference was from a debian wiki

Comment: And yes, squid would be a fine proxy to use.

Comment: The proxy was perfect.  Had to hardcode the IP as evidently google's nameservers are not accessible.  Thanks!